# Google Cloud Vision to detect only one language

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, google-cloud-vision

Is there any way to specify the language that we need to extract from an image.

for example:  I have an image that contains arabic+ french characters and the API returns a mixed text , is there a way to extract only french characters

Comment: From the doc, you can specify the language. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#specifying_the_language

Answer (score 0):

You can use `languageHints` inside an `imageContext` request seting it to 'fr' for example:

```
 "requests": [
    {
      "imageContext": {
        "languageHints": [
          "fr"
        ]
```

You can test it [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#imagecontext)