# How can I make google vision APi detect only one language? (especially not to detect English!!)

Tags: javascript, google-api, vision

I looked for answers to many similar questions.

[Google Cloud Vision to detect only one language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710122/google-cloud-vision-to-detect-only-one-language)

And I found [this page.](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/ImageContext)

From what I understand, the way to solve this problem was:

```js
      const result = await axios.post(
        `${API.TEXT_ENDPOINT}?key=${process.env.API_KEY}`,
        {
          requests: [
            {
              image: {
                content: canvas
                  .toDataURL()
                  .replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, ""),
              },
              features: [
                {
                  type: "TEXT_DETECTION",
                  maxResults: 1,
                },
              ],
              imageContext: {
                languageHints: ["ko"],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        },
      );
```

However, if I write this way, it seems that **English is recognized unconditionally** along with the language I have designated.

This page says;

> List of languages to use for TEXT_DETECTION. In most cases, an empty
> value yields the best results since it enables automatic language
> detection. **For languages based on the Latin alphabet, setting
> languageHints is not needed.** In rare cases, when the language of the
> text in the image is known, setting a hint will help get better
> results (although it will be a significant hindrance if the hint is
> wrong). Text detection returns an error if one or more of the
> specified languages is not one of the supported languages.

How can I make the vision APi detect only one language? **(especially not to detect English!!)**